# Restlet using Get and Post Methods

Tags: restlet

Hiiii,

I am developing a small app using Restlet 2.0 API..

I want just to know how to create a URI which accepts more than one parameter for insert query.

Ex:

```
router.attach("/{patient}/insertpatient", insertpatient);
```

I want to insert all the info about the patient using POST.

Or Search by ID and address for instance using GET.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For the "insert patient" operation, I'd suggest something like a POST to /patients (if the server generates the patient ID) or a PUT to /patients/{patient-id} (if the client generates the patient ID).  Either way, the body of the message would contain all of the input data needed to create a new patient entity.  Two simple options for serializing the data would be as a URL-encoded form or as JSON.

Lookup by by ID could be a simple as a GET on /patients/{patient-id}.  Lookup by address could also be a GET, possibly using a URL-encoded query parameter.  For example, you could fetch the patient at address "123 Main Street, apt 4, Anytown, USA, 98765" with a GET on /patients?addr=%20Main%20Street%2C%20apt%204%2C%20Anytown%2C%20USA%2C%2098765

Comment: so can you provide me with a code example for the PUT method for both client and server because I already did it but an error pops up indicating that the media type is not supported..

Comment: as for the put method thank God it's resolved, but can you provide me with sample code of how to fetch patient using bith ID and address..

Comment: sorry, I can't right now, as I'm away and won't be back at my computer for a few days.  Perhaps someone else who is following this question could assist?